# Angular: Call method from route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there a way to call a (static) method from a service when going to a route?

Something like:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
   { path: 'logout', method: AuthService.logout() }
])
```

So I can navigate to http://localhost/logout and then a method will be called. I think that making a component for this is a bit much.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, this is not possible. You have to create a component for that.

Comment: I do not see any property in Angular `Routes` that allows for a direct method call from the route configuration. https://angular.io/api/router/Routes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No sense in having a route without a view, so no it can't be done. But hey, you can simply call logout() from a (click) binding on a link or any.

Well actually, could be done with a canActivate guard on the route. In it you'd log out and return false to prevent navigation or navigate somewhere else. Very hacky and doesn't reduce complexity vs. a component, or a simple `(click)="authService.logout()"`. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!